Troubleshooting error 17830 with various states
I have a SQL Server 2019 instance (build 15.0.4365.2. (CU26)) that is continuously seeing severity 20 errors with error number 17830.  The state values vary, mostly state 11, sometimes we see state 105, and very occasionally 12, 102, and 103.  The SQL Server is configured with forced encryption, and it has a trusted valid SSL certificate.
Errors are similar to:

Network error code 0x2746 occurred while establishing a connection; the connection has been closed. This may have been caused by client or server login timeout expiration. Time spent during login: total 4 ms, enqueued 4 ms, network writes 0 ms, network reads 0 ms, establishing SSL 0 ms, network reads during SSL 0 ms, network writes during SSL 0 ms, secure calls during SSL 0 ms, enqueued during SSL 0 ms, negotiating SSPI 0 ms, network reads during SSPI 0 ms, network writes during SSPI 0 ms, secure calls during SSPI 0 ms, enqueued during SSPI 0 ms, validating login 0 ms, including user-defined login processing 0 ms. [CLIENT: x.x.x.x]

I've read Bob Dorr's article here about it.  This is similar to what we're seeing:

the timings were always small and not something the SQL Server engine was doing, instead the client was closing the connection.

Is there some way to determine more about this error aside from doing packet capture and using deduction?  i.e. is there some place that documents the meanings of the state values for error 17830?
DBCC CHECKDB automatically runs nightly.  CU28 is scheduled for install in September.  Our platform is fully cloud-based, IaaS, preventing us from being able to manually check physical connections, networking, firewall, etc.
